# ASUS UX534FT sound issues

Tags: 18.04, sound, alsa, asus, headphones

I recently bought an ASUS ZenBook UX534FT and installed Ubuntu for some work with ROS. Unfortunately, I am unable to hear any sound after the install, both through inbuilt speakers or headphones(no trouble detecting headphones).

I checked through `pavucontrol` and `alsamixer` to make sure that the devices aren't muted. It looks like a similar issue has been reported for the previous generation ZenBooks [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1826645) . However, I'm not really familiar with Ubuntu to make sense of this.

Comment: It looks this problem is described in more detail in another askubuntu post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175095/asus-zenbook-ux534f-no-sound-from-speakers-headphones. How do I collapse my question into that post?